# How to kick an user session? [node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, passport.js, passport-local

my system use passport.js for authentication.
users are able to login and logout base on local strategies.
I am working on a function that allow super user to kick an user from my system.

my current approach is to :

1. set the user profile as disable
2. delete the user session
3. the user cannot login again because the user profile was disable(using local strategies)

How could I delete the user session in MongoStore?

```
"express": "~4.13.1",
"express-session": "~1.11.3",
"mongoose": "~4.0.7",
"passport": "~0.2.2",
"passport-local": "~1.0.0",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find all the user sessions in the sessions-collection in mongo and del them. Explore the collection using mongo cli. Then use mongo-native or mongoose module to del.